# How do I change this to see a picture not text?

Tags: var, timetable

I made this a long time ago now I want that the text output is a picture what must I do. Thanks.

```
document.write("<p>");
    var day = new Date();
    var weekday = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
    var d = weekday[day.getDay()];
    var hr = day.getHours();
    if (hr == 1 && d == "Sunday") {
        document.write("Nachtlijn");
    } else if (hr == 2 && d == "Sunday") {
        document.write("Nachtlijn");
    } else if (hr == 3 && d == "Sunday") {
```

Comment: Question is not clear. put full code and add some description about problem you are facing.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.